# Unable to Export Data to from R to Vertica

Tags: r, google-sheets, export, vertica, rjdbc

It will be Great if anyone an help me out with COPY function syntax.

I am trying to copy data from google Doc to [vertica](/questions/tagged/vertica) with the help of [r](/questions/tagged/r) (using [google-sheets](/questions/tagged/google-sheets) and `RJDBC` Package).

I have exported the data from google sheet but unable to import in `Vertica` server.

Please Help me out.

```
googleSheet <- gs_title("GS", verbose = FALSE)
auditSheet  <- gs_read(ss = googleSheet, ws = 'GS1')
```

> copy verticaDB.tableName from local auditSheet

Thanks

Comment: I would experiment with the COPY command from a file - reading the manual. Remember that you need a table already created with the structure of the data you want to import. From R - even if I'm not an expert, I would explore the `COPY <schema>.<tablename> FROM STDIN` command. And I would expect that you need to create a dataframe in R. I'm not sure if you need an INSERT statement with parameter markers or if you can use `COPY ... FROM STDIN`

Comment: I'm not an "R" programmer - but can you export `googleSheet` or `auditSheet` to a CSV file, with ',' as the column delimiter and '"' (double quote) as the string encloser?

Comment: Then you could use Vertica like so:
`CREATE FLEX TABLE googlesheet();`
`COPY googlesheet FROM LOCAL 'yourfile.csv' PARSER FCSVPARSER();`
`SELECT COMPUTE_FLEXTABLE_KEYS_AND_BUILD_VIEW('googlesheet');`
.. and finally:
`SELECT * FROM googlesheet_view LIMIT 10;` to see the first 10 rows in your flex table.